# javascriptでthisが未定義と怒られてしまう

Tags: javascript, vue.js

現在、JavaScriptの勉強をしている初心者です。
以下、コードをデバックしており、"let res_ = await this.callApi("
の箇所で、callApiが未定義ですと怒られてしまいます。

以下コードにはcallApiに関する記述がございませんが、
確かに記述をしており、”let values = await this.callApi(this.METHOD.GET,....”
の箇所は実行できていることから、なぜ未定義と怒られるのかがわかりません。
どのように記述をすれば、読み込んでくれるのでしょうか。

ご教授いただけないでしょうか。よろしくお願い致します。

```
async test() {
      const {hennsu1, hennsu2,hennsu3} = this.info;
      // Get global IP
      const network_info = await fetch(this.GET_GLOBAL_IP)
        .then(res => res.json())

      let values = await this.callApi(this.METHOD.GET,`${this.URL_ENDPOINT.AAAA}/${this.AAAA.XXXXXXXX}`);

      var camera_url = ''
      var success_code = this.STATUS_CODE.SUCCESS

      if (values && values.code == this.STATUS_CODE.SUCCESS) {
        let duration = null
        bootbox.prompt({
            title: this.title,
            message: this.messege,
            inputType: 'radio',
            inputOptions: [{
                text: values.payload[0].explanation,
                value: values.payload[0].value
            },
            {
                text: values.payload[1].explanation,
                value: values.payload[1].value
            }],
            callback: async function (result) {
              if (result != null){
                let res_ = await this.callApi(
                  this.METHOD.GET,
                  `${this.URL_ENDPOINT.xxx}/${network_info.ip}/${result}/${hennsu1}/${hennsu2}`);

                if (res_ && res_.code == success_code) {
                  camera_url = `http://${res_.payload.xxxx}:${res_.payload.xxxxX}/${hennsu3 === null? '' : hennsu3}`;
                  window.open(camera_url, '_blank');
                }
              }
            }
        });
      } else {
        const msg = res && res.message? res.message: this.UNEXPECTED_ERR;
        bootbox.alert(msg);
      }
    },
```

Comment: 問題が起きるソース全体とcallApiが定義されているファイル、依存関係が分かるように記載してください。

Comment: 言葉が足りず、申し訳ございません。。。

Answer (score 0):

この `callback: async function (result) {` が呼ばれるときに `this` が何になるのかは `bootbox.prompt()` の仕様実装に依存します。

アロー関数に変えるとか `.bind(this)` を付けるなどで `this` を固定しましょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます！教えていただいた内容で、解決しました。